# How to call a vuex action in component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have created a vuex with some actions and I want to call those actions in component. I tried to map it but in response I am getting 404.

This is my VueX for `stockist.js` -

```
import api from '@shiba/src/api';

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    actions: {
        get_store_names: () => {
            return api.get('stockist/get-store-names').then((response) => {
                return response.data;
            });
        },
    },
};
```

I want to call `get_store_names` in component called `shipping-method` using `mapState` -

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
    //some code
    computed: {
        ...mapState('stockist'),
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getStores();
    },

    methods: {
        getStores() {
            this.$store.dispatch('stockist/get_store_names').then((response) => {
                console.log(response); //getting 404
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: A http 404 error means the API endpoint you are trying to access is wrong. Are you getting a 404 http error?

Comment: I check the request url but it response code is 200. But in it's response it is redirecting to 404.

Comment: In the browser dev tools, navigate to network tab. Then reload your vue application and you can see the exact url the request is made to. Maybe the api end point is appended incorrectly. You can debug this using the network tab in the browser dev tools. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. I tried. But same error.

Comment: You have a typo in your call to action. Your namespaced store is in a file called “stocklist.js” but you are calling a namespace called “stockist”. Is this the same in your original code?

Comment: Oh. Sorry, It was my typo while writing a question. Corrected it. It is stockist.js. I am not sure what is the issue. Is code correct?

Comment: Code seems ok. Can you update your answer with the exact error you’re getting

Comment: The problem is there is no any error. Request seems fine. Getting 200 as a response code. But in response it shows 404 page.

Comment: Is it 200 or 404? Do you get "not found" page on request with 200 code? Then blame API on it, Vue part is likely irrelevant. It's unclear what you mean, please, be more specific.